# Can Git pull from one Subversion repository and push to another Subversion repository?

Tags: svn, git

I have a development team working on one [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subversion_%28software%29) repository and another team working on another SVN repository. The projects are similar but slight different hence 2 development servers.

Occasionally I would like to push and pull some features from one team to another.

Can [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) do the job? Any suggestion on how to go about it? (Git beginner user)

(The 2nd SVN repository was spawned from the 1st SVN repository.)

Answer (score 1):

Although Git has features for interfacing with Subversion, it's really only designed to interface with *one* Subversion repository at a time.

You may be best off managing changes by managing patch files manually. Even though one Subversion repository was forked from another, `git svn` is going to see them as having totally different history.